# If I make a sikuli script in Windows, will the same script work in Linux?

Tags: sikuli

I am currently looking for a tool to test a a website and Sikuli seems perfect. However, my company uses both Windows and Linux, and I'd like our scripts to be transferable.

Will it work or are Windows scripts for Windows and Linux scripts for Linux?
It seems like Sikuli can be run from the [command line](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html), perhaps I can run the same script on both the Linux and Windows Computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical reason why a Sikuli script won't run under both operating systems (jython has the same syntax on both platforms).  The biggest technical issue faced is that the screenshots may not match between Windows and Linux.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641327/what-are-strategies-to-construct-reusable-sikuli-screen-shot-libraries/9642562#9642562) discusses how to setup two images pools, one for each OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I think I came to the conclusion that Sikuli is not the right tool for me; I need something that can run in the background, that doesn't need a screen.

Answer (score 1):

there are two main points to be concerned of:

1. Images: Even if the application looks the same in both the systems the ways to launch it are different. In the worst case one needs two complete sets of images.
2. Paths: In Windows and Linux paths are different. Different slashes, different lengths of the whole paths and components, different set of allowed symbols in the naming. Windows paths are not case sensitive by default.

There are some points to use the same script still with set of OS specific libraries. 
- The more common logic in applications the more reusable code. 
- The policy "changing something are must for both platforms". is easy to follow.

So the answer for your question is:
Specially prepared script will work on both the platforms

Answer (score 1):

Creating Sikuli scipts directly in java might ease the cross platform issues. But you will still have the images looking slightly different issue. File directories are handled well accros OS in java though.